# Firefox - display basic authentication settings

Tags: firefox, authentication

Is there an option or other means in Firefox that will indicate whether I am authenticated to a given site via basic authentication?

E.g., I visit my webserver and login using basic auth.

I would like a little green button or something showing me that I am logged in, preferably also containing the name of the user I am logged in as.

***EDIT***:  I am looking for a GUI element that I can glance at and see immediately something like "Authenticated as g33kz0r".  I don't want to have to click anything or dig into hierarchical menus to find the information.

Comment: @Dave Rook I've been using Firefox since version 1.0.  This has never been an option as far as I'm aware (in FF or any browser).  (I also googled and searched this site for similar questions before posting.)

Comment: Well, I tried to edit your question and remove the extension. You've put it back on. I've voted to close, software/tools etc recommendations are off topic

Comment: @DaveRook I put it back in because it seems reasonable that the answer to my question might be an extension and not an option.  Maybe you could point me to the reference you're relying on to say my question is O/T?

Comment: Yes, you need to be careful with how it is worded :). We can reply with extensions/software suggestions, but you can't ask for it! I'd remove it, if some one knows of anything then they will suggest it :)